# Need help converting Apache2 Rewrite rules to nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I've managed to convert most of them, but I'm struggling a bit with these two -

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteRule !^(media/(.+)|favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap-main.xml)$ index.php
```

Would appreciate a hand if anyone is a nginx rewrite ninja :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

will be converted to:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)/$ http://$http_host/$1 permanent;
```

and this:

```
RewriteRule !^(media/(.+)|favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap-main.xml)$ index.php
```

will be converted to:

```
rewrite /!^(media/(.+)|favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap-main.xml)$ /index.php;
```

you can also use:

```
if ($rule_0 = ""){
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ http://$http_host/$1 permanent;
}
if ($rule_0 = ""){
    rewrite /!^(media/(.+)|favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap-main.xml)$ /index.php;
}
```

Documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

From: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

Comment: Thanks - appreciate it. I would upvote you...but I don't enough reputation yet!

Comment: No problem, the higher accepted answer ratio you have, the better chance you will have quality answers. Welcome to StackOverFlow.

Comment: Oh that's great, thanks. Got enough privileges to upvote the answer now - so I've done so :)